# How to use a foreign key?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, application-design

I'm creating the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE fund_identifier
(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    identifier TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS fund_identifier_pkey ON fund_identifier (id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS fund_identifier_identifier_uindex ON fund_identifier (identifier)
```

However, I'm not sure what would be the best practice to use *identifier* as a foreign key. Should I use as reference the value of the foreign key like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE security_papers (
      id                                        BIGSERIAL,
      fund_identifier                           TEXT,
      as_of_date                                DATE,
          ...
      CONSTRAINT security_papers_fund_identifier_fk FOREIGN KEY (fund_identifier) REFERENCES fund_identifier (identifier)
    }
```

Or, should I use its `id`? Like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE security_papers (
      id                                        BIGSERIAL,
      fund_identifier_id                        BIGSERIAL,
      as_of_date                                DATE,
          ...
      CONSTRAINT security_papers_fund_identifier_fk FOREIGN KEY (fund_identifier) REFERENCES fund_identifier (identifier)
    }
```

My guess is on the second approach when it comes to the normalization rules. On the logical side, my application would need to look for  the id of `fund_identifier` first, before persisting anything at `security_papers` table. Right ?

But if I go with the second approach, this would be delegated to the database. Making my application logic, easier to implement.

Please let me know your thoughts, and if I'm missing some concept here. Thank you!

Comment: I think there is a type on the 2nd: `CONSTRAINT security_papers_fund_identifier_fk FOREIGN KEY (fund_identifier) REFERENCES fund_identifier (identifier)` should be: `CONSTRAINT security_papers_fund_identifier_fk FOREIGN KEY (fund_identifier_id) REFERENCES fund_identifier (id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table seems to have a perfectly good key candidate (*identifier*) yet you also create a surrogate key. Why? (I do not hold to the rule that all tables *must* have a surrogate key.)

However, once you create a surrogate key, that is generally the field used to reference rows in that table. Even when importing outside data that contains the text value in *identifier*, it is converted to the key value when stored.

In other words, almost without exception, the only place you will find the text identifier values will be in the *identifier* field of the *fund_identifier* table. This eliminates ambiguous data and simplifies maintenance.

Answer (score 4):

> However, I'm not sure what would be the best practice to use identifier as a foreign key. Should I use as reference the value of the foreign key like this

A couple of points before hand.

- There is no need to mark a `PRIMARY KEY` `NOT NULL`, and DO NOT create a `UNIQUE` index on it. That'll just slow things down. It's already implemented with a ``UNIQUE` index.
- Reconsider bigserial, do you really need it?
- If you do **not** use `id`, but instead `fund_id`, or `id_fund` or the like, you can use the `USING (fund_id)` clause which is

  - easier to type
  - less error-prone
- PostgreSQL provides for a shorter more terse syntax to refer to primary keys..

  ```
  -- it'll guess primary key
  fund_identifier  type  REFERENCES table;
  ```

That said, I think your questions is if your primary table uses `bigserial` how does your foreign table declare the column that refers to it.. Like this, using `bigint`

```
fund_identifier  bigint  REFERENCES table;
```

So your schema should look like

```
CREATE TABLE funds (
    id_fund    bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    identifier text      UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE security_papers (
  id_security_paper    bigserial  NOT NULL
  id_fund              bigint     REFERENCES funds
  as_of_date           date,
);
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM security_papers
JOIN funds
  USING (id_fund);
```

Comment: The funny thing about the `UNIQUE INDEX` is that it was created by `IntelliJ` database toolbox, I will remove it then :D